# Math error in blog post on web3

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

From yesterday's [blog post on web3](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/04/20/new-data-developers-web3/?cb=1):

> Of the 595 developers surveyed, a sizable portion had no idea what we were talking about: 36% responded with “What’s Web3?” Of those in the know, 25% think Web3 is the future of the internet, 15% think it’s a bunch of hype, 14% think it’s important for crypto and related apps, and 9% think it’s all a scam.

This paragraph is followed by a graphic with different data:

> [image: What do developers think of Web3]

There are several errors here when comparing the text to the graphic:

1. The text reads "36% responded with 'What’s Web3?'" while the graphic shows this number at 37%.
2. The rest of the values in the text are rounded to the nearest percent compared to the graphic, but with 36% replacing 37%, the total comes to 99%.
3. The percentages following "Of those in the know" are actually out of the total of 595 developers surveyed, not just out of the 381 (595 - 36%) or 375 (595 - 37%):

| Category | % of total | Qty | "Those in the know" % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - the future | 25.4% | 151 | 40.3% |
| - hype | 15.1% | 90 | 24.0% |
| - important | 13.6% | 81 | 21.6% |
| - scam | 8.9% | 53 | 14.1% |
| **Subtotal** | 63.0% | 375 | 100.0% |
| - What's web3 | 37.0% | 220 | - |

These values should either be recalculated to be out of 381/375 who know what Web3 is, or the text should read something like "in the remaining categories for those who know what Web3 is..."

Comment: Those pesky truncate/round functions!

Answer (score 5):

Those off-by-one errors are legion. I've fixed this, and we'll use whole number percentages in the future to avoid this issue.